Mediasoup client device not properly loading video capability with proper rtp capabilites
I am trying to load a mediasoup client device with the rtpCapabilities I have received from my server, in order to create video streams on my website. However, the device I am creating keeps returning an object with this: _canProduceByKind: {audio: false, video: false}, and therefore whenever I try to create my producer transport, it says 'UnsupportedError: cannot produce video'.
Here is the full device object returned when console logged:
{
    "_loaded": true,
    "_observer": {
        "_events": {},
        "_eventsCount": 0,
        "_maxListeners": null
    },
    "_handlerName": "Chrome111",
    "_extendedRtpCapabilities": {
        "codecs": [],
        "headerExtensions": []
    },
    "_recvRtpCapabilities": {
        "codecs": [],
        "headerExtensions": []
    },
    "_canProduceByKind": {
        "audio": false,
        "video": false
    },
    "_sctpCapabilities": {
        "numStreams": {
            "OS": 1024,
            "MIS": 1024
        }
    }
}

Here are the rtpCababilites being passed in load:
{
    "rtpCapabilities": {
        "codecs": [
            {
                "kind": "audio",
                "mimeType": "audio/opus",
                "clockRate": 48000,
                "channels": 2,
                "rtcpFeedback": [
                    {
                        "type": "nack",
                        "parameter": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "transport-cc",
                        "parameter": ""
                    }
                ],
                "parameters": {},
                "preferredPayloadType": 100
            },
            {
                "kind": "video",
                "mimeType": "video/VP8",
                "clockRate": 90000,
                "rtcpFeedback": [
                    {
                        "type": "nack",
                        "parameter": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "nack",
                        "parameter": "pli"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ccm",
                        "parameter": "fir"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "goog-remb",
                        "parameter": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "transport-cc",
                        "parameter": ""
                    }
                ],
                "parameters": {
                    "x-google-start-bitrate": 1000
                },
                "preferredPayloadType": 101
            },
            {
                "kind": "video",
                "mimeType": "video/rtx",
                "preferredPayloadType": 102,
                "clockRate": 90000,
                "parameters": {
                    "apt": 101
                },
                "rtcpFeedback": []
            }
        ],
        "headerExtensions": [
           {All the video headers.... alot of them}
        ]
    }
}

Here is how I am initializing the device:
    const createDevice = async () => {
        try{

            console.log(mediasoupClient)
            console.log('RtpCapabilities', rtpCapabilities)

            deviceRef.current  = new mediasoupClient.Device()
                await deviceRef.current.load({
                    routerRtpCapabilities: rtpCapabilities
                })

        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err)
            if(err.name === 'UnsupportedError'){
                console.warn('browser not supported')
            }
        }
    }

I have checked the rtp capabilities before initializing and I am indeed sending them in to load correctly.
I have checked my mediasoup client and am returning version: '3.7.14',
If anyone can help me with this headache that would be amazing! Thanks!!

I sent in an object with an object rtpCapabilities instead of the rtpCapabilities object itself and am now currently rolling my face into my keyboard because of the 3 hours I wasted checking documentation. PROGRAMMING IS FUN!!
